# Can't connect to SVN repository through SvnKit API

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnkit

We have a SVN repository, and I am able to connect to it through Tortoise. But when I try to connect to it through SvnKit, specifically `svnRepository.testConnection()` method, it says
`svn: E170001: Authentication required for ...`. The credentials passed in are the same ones I am using with Tortoise as well.

This particular component works fine with other repositories. Further, this repository is secured. But I am able to connect to other secure repositories as well.

Here's the error log.

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: Authentication required for 'server name:443'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.java:47)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.java:41)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.auth.BasicAuthenticationManager.getNextAuthentication(BasicAuthenticationManager.java:223)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:657)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:362)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:350)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:708)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:628)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:103)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1016)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.testConnection(DAVRepository.java:99)
```

Looking forward to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: call

```
svnRepository.setAuthenticationManager(...);
```

with a proper ISVNAuthenticationManager implementation.

SVNKit has already several ready-to-use implementations of this class. The simplest one is `BasicAuthenticationManager` which can be constructed by one or several `SVNAuthentication`. Each `SVNAuthentication` instance represents some kind of credentials (see its subclasses).
So if, for example, your repository is secured by only username and password, you can construct `SVNPasswordAuthentication` with your password and then construct `BasicAuthenticationManager` using it and pass to `SVNRepository`.

Another useful implementation is `DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager` which describes "authentication data stored in `~/.subversion` directory". To construct it you can use `SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager()`. You can also customize this class, for example, to allow or disallow to enter a password from a keyboard in interactive mode, or to store or not to store entered password in in `~/.subversion` directory (or also you can use another directory for that). To understand how to do that, I recommend you to look at `SVNCommandEnvironment.createClientAuthenticationManager()` which constructs  `ISVNAuthenticationManager` implementation for command line utility.

Comment: Still facing the same issue. Here's the stack trace.

at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.java:47)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.java:41)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.auth.BasicAuthenticationManager.getNextAuthentication(BasicAuthenticationManager.java:223)

Comment: This means that none of credentials you've provided can be used for authorization at the repository. What you can do: 1) download SVNKit command line utility, and check that it works for you 2) run org.tmatesoft.svn.cli.SVN class and debug it to see what ISVNAuthenticationManager instance is constructed.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Will do that and let you know how it goes